# set env variables for pipeline subshells independently

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Been wondering this for awhile but keep forgetting to ask

if we have a pipeline like this:

```
a | b
```

is there a way to set env variables separately, something like this:

```
x="foo" a | x="bar" b
```

Comment: Did you try it? Your "something like this" works fine.

Comment: hmmmm `x="foo" echo "$x" | x="bar" echo "$x"` doesn't work fine afaict

Comment: That's not the same thing as in your question. The shell is expanding `$x`, not `echo`. Try with an application that actually uses the var internally.

Comment: oh i see, that makes sense

Comment: @Patrick I think this is worth to be given as an answer. Maybe including a `function echox() { echo "$x"; }` example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you like to do is in conflict with the standard because the standard defines that shell macro expansion takes place before the specific environment is set up.

There is still a way to do what you like since POSIX requires environment statements before a `special shell builtin` to affect the whole shell. The `:` command  is such a `special shell builtin`.

Try:

```
(x="foo" :; a) | (x="bar" :; b)
```

This needs to be done in a subshell, in order to prevent the main shell process to be affected. If you replace `a` and `b` by `echo $x,` this will now print what the OP expected in his comment:

```
(x="foo" :; echo $x) | (x="bar" :; echo $x)
```

Well, the output from the left side of the pipe is lost...

But since you already need to use a subshell, you may use:

```
 (x="foo"; echo $x) | (x="bar"; echo $x)
```

which uses the syntax to first set a shell variable in the subshell and then use it. If you need `x` as an environment in the commands, you need to `export x` in the latter example.

Comment: There is no expansion going on in the original question. There was expansion going on in the comment, but the comment was an attempt to to test the solution, but was a bad method to test. Also your solution will not work as the variable will only be defined for `:`. When `a`  and `b` run, the variable will be undefined.

Comment: You are mistaken: Read the POSIX standard -> as said, `:` is a so called `special builtin command` that grants to keep the modified environment in the shell process that calls `:`. In my example, this is the subshell from the`()`.  Since that shell already has the modified value in `x`, it will print what the OP expects.

Comment: That's POSIX specifying an accident of implementation of the Korn shell (inherited from the Bourne shell). Since that behaviour otherwise makes little sense several modern shell implementations (including `bash` and `zsh`) don't do it or only do it in some conformance mode for those shells that seek POSIX compliance. Here adding that `:` doesn't make any sense. `(x=foo; echo $x) | (x=bar; echo $x)` will work just the same and be more portable and legible.

Comment: Your simplified example works, thank you! But please note that the Korn Shell and modern Bourne Shell versions implement both variants: builtins with private environment and builtins that retain the environment in the calling shell process. Since these implementations control their behavior by an entry in a  structure array, the different behavior in `special builtins` was a willful decision.

Comment: Actually `(x=-foo; echo $x) | (x=bar; echo $x)` doesn't work either. The variable is unexported. This means it only works for cases where the shell is expanding `$x`. The variable is not made available to the program being run, which seems to be what the user is asking. All the proposals in this answer do not work. The correct solution is the one already specified in the question.

Comment: Well, the OP did ask for a way to use `$x` in the command line, there is no need to export x for that kind of usage.